# ProtonVPN on Windows 10: Use only for specific websties or specific browsers

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, openvpn

Are any of the things possible with ProtonVPN on Windows 10

1. Is it possible to use ProtonVPN on Windows only from a particular browser -i.e. after connecting to Proton, if I am using 1 browser, it should go through the VPN, while another browser should use the native connection
2. Irrespective of browser, only some routes should go through the VPN, others through the native connection.
3. Opp of (2) - Only some routes through native connection, others through VPN

Proton VPN has an article on how to do one of the above on MacOS - https://protonvpn.com/support/vpn-bypass-macos/

But is any of this possible at all on Windows 10.
https://protonvpn.com/support/vpn-bypass-macos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely easy to do on Windows 10, instructions below and reference:

1. Open ProtonVPN
2. select Settings in the app menu
3. Then click on the Advanced tab and slide the “Split Tunneling” switch to ON
4. The web browsers installed on your device will then appear in a drop menu. By selecting a browser, you will exclude it from our VPN service and allow it to use your regular connection.
5. You can also select specific IP addresses that you do not want our VPN to cover by typing/pasting the IP address to be excluded into the space and clicking on the + button.
6. List item

Done

[Windows 10 ProtonVPN split-tunnelling](https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-split-tunneling/)